# PyQt5. How to get cursor position in QTextEdit connected with ContextMenu?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to get cursor position in `QTextEdit`:

```
class CustomEdit(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
       super(CustomEdit, self).__init__()
       self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
       self.cursor = self.textCursor()
       self.menu = None
       self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.create_menu)

    def create_menu(self, pos):
        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        func = self.menu.addAction(u'function')
        action = self.menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action == func:
            self.func()

    def func(self)
            print(self.cursor.positionInBlock())
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: It returns wrong number that not correlated with cursor position

Comment: I correct copy past from project. Self - it is argument of this function as part of class that inherited from QTextEdit

Comment: @eyllanesc,  pyqt5

Comment: relative position of the cursor within the block

Comment: I tried your code by `PySide`,I can show the contextmenu on the `QTextEdit`.If you click with right mouse button,the context menu pops up at that position,right?`positionInBlock()` returned 0

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but I was looking for this too and found out that you can use `self.QTextEdit.textCursor().position()` to get an integer of the cursor position.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30623379)